# Angular how to set navbar fixed?

Tags: css, angular, navbar

I have created a navbar with this command `ng generate @angular/material:material-nav --name=home` and I want my navbar to be fixed on the top when I am scrolling down.

I tried `position: fixed;` with my mat-sidenav-content but it didn't worked. You guys have any idea how I can do this?

navbar.component.html

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav #drawer class="sidenav" fixedInViewport="false"
      [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
      [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
      [opened]="(isHandset$ | async) === false">
    <mat-toolbar>Menu</mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 3</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
      <button
        type="button"
        aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
        mat-icon-button
        (click)="drawer.toggle()"
        *ngIf="isHandset$ | async">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <span>checkout</span>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <!-- Add Content Here -->
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

navbar.component.ts

```
  isHandset$: Observable<boolean> = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset)
    .pipe(
      map(result => result.matches),
      shareReplay()
    );

  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `fixedInViewport` from `false` to `true`.

Comment: If i understand well the documentation, fixedInViewport is used for sidenav and not for the whole container.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but sadly if I change it to true my sidenav keeps open. I will continue to try.

Answer (score 0):

If you have content(s) above sidenav you can use position sticky:

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container" style="position:sticky; top: 0">
....
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

But unfortunately, it is not supported by all browsers (https://caniuse.com/css-sticky).

The second way, you can use position fixed (in this case there should be no element above it):

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container" style="position:fixed; width: 100%; top: 0">
....
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: Thanks! But sadly if I use position sticky, it causes a second scroll bar on my page and I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: you can use overflow: hidden for unnecessary element's scroll